# I couldn't get expected result in c# programming using Substring() and Remove()

Tags: c#, substring

I'm stuck with Substring () and Remove ().

I expected that both first and second results would be "P".

However, first result showed "PHP" (false) while second result showed "P" (true).

I have no idea why first result displays false result.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace prac10
{
    class prac
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string line = "PHP";
            WriteLine((line.Substring(0,1).Equals("PH") ? line.Remove(0,1) : line));
            WriteLine((line.Substring(1, 2).Equals("HP") ? line.Remove(1, 2) : line));
```

Comment: `line.Substring(0,1)` is "P", not "PH". Note that the second parameter is the length of the string to be extracted, not the last index.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `Substring` method of C# does work a little different like the one in Java.

The method `Substring` has two variants:

```
public string Substring (int startIndex);
public string Substring (int startIndex, int length);
```

As you see from the parameter names, the second parameters is there to determine the length of the string.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0